# why the static variable's value is same while i changed it in method

Tags: java, variables, static

```
public class Demorun 
      {
    static int x=20;

    public static void change(int x){
        x=10;
        System.out.println("inside x: "+x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        change(x);
        System.out.println("outside x: "+x);
    }
}
```

output

```
inside x: 10
outside x: 20
```

Since there is only one copy of the static variable then why is the value of `x` is still `20`? Why is the change made in method `change()` not making a permanent change of the static variable?

Comment: `x=10;` is changing the value of your local variable which is also called `x`. Use `Demorun.x=10;` to access the static field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to pass `x` as an argument to `change`, and the fact that it's shadowing the member variable is the cause of the undesired behavior (your `change` function is just modifying the argument instead of the member variable).

The following code is simpler and would have the desired effect:

```
public class Demorun
{
    static int x = 20;

    public static void change()
    {
        x = 10;
        System.out.println("inside x: " + x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        change();
        System.out.println("outside x: " + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for clearing my doubt. i was using "x" as my static variable's name as well as method parameter name i think that was the reason i got confused

Answer (score 1):

When you call `change(x)`, you're passing in a copy of the variable `x`, not `x` itself. There is no pass-by-reference in Java; this is pass-by-value. If you want to change the outer `x`, do:

```
x = change(x);
```

and modify `change(x)` to:

```
public static  void change(int x){
    x=10;
    System.out.println("intside x: "+x);
    return x;
 }
```

or not pass in `x` at all to the `change()` method.